# crt.sh shows certificates for domains I don't recognize

Tags: tls, certificates, letsencrypt, certificate-transparency

Today I learned of the existence of [crt.sh](https://crt.sh). I typed one of my domain names into the search box to find out what it returns. I found a lot of certificate entries for domains that I don't recognize, and which appear spammy to me. Many of them use a subdomain of `mail`. Is this something I should be concerned about? Is there any relevant information I should be looking for?

Note: I use Let's Encrypt for my certificates, and it appears that the other certs are also from them--at least the ones I've looked at.

### To answer questions from the comments

1. There are both recent (current) and historical entries.
2. There is a mix of precertificates and leaf certificates. There might be others, too, since I haven't examined all of the many entries.
3. I don't use a CDN, but it's possible that my webhost might do some aggregation since it's a shared host and I'm using the certificate generation tool and cronjob they provide.
4. It appears that most of the domains I don't recognize are of the form `mail.TLD`, with "mail" sometimes using a different-language equivalent. So could this have something to do with my email hosting provider?

Comment: Recent entries or historical ones?

Comment: Both. I'm looking at one with a timestamp of 2023-09-18, which says it's a precertificate. I don't know what a precertificate is.

Comment: Please look up terms you don't know: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/glossary/#def-precertificate

Comment: I read the definition of a precertificate, but I don't understand them enough to be able to form an informed opinion. There are a lot of entries to go through, but it appears that the majority of the certificates I don't recognize are precertificates. However, I've seen one so far which is still valid which is a leaf certificate.

Comment: Do you use a CDN? CDNs (e.g. Cloudflare) often create certs with 1000 domains that have nothing in common and use those on their edge servers.

Comment: I don't use a CDN. But I wonder if my web host does something similar.

Comment: Or maybe my email provider, since the majority of domains included are mail.TLD or correo.TLD or something similar.

Comment: It seems like you're letting your e-mail provider manage your domain, hence the unexpected records I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've discovered the answer. The common denominator for all these domains appears to be that they use Zoho email. Each of the domains I tested resolves to Zoho, so presumably the certificates were created by Zoho to enable their webapp to run on a client's subdomain.

Comment: Zoho is just an webapp and if it doesn't have access to your DNS zone or similar, it won't be able to make those ACME requests

Comment: There's more to Zoho than just a webapp. To enable it to process mail on my behalf, I have to point MX records to it. I've also set up a subdomain to host the webapp.

Comment: Fair point I guess